# Building a Gatsby blog connected to Contentful CMS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful

So, the issue i have really boggles me. I have access to a variable from a Contentful field, but i don't for the other 4 that are placed in identical fields as the first one, all in the same content model. This is my query:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query blogPostQuery($slug: String!) {
    contentfulBlog(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      product1Title
      product2Title
      product3Title
      product4Title
      product5Title
    }
  }
`
```

[Terminal screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR2Jn.png)

In terminal it seems i get:

> GraphQL Error Unknown field `product2Title` on type `ContentfulBlog`

If i delete product2Title from the query, i get the error at product3Title and so on. product1 works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you see in the GraphiQL inspector at http://localhost:8000/___graphql ? If you open the documentation (link top right), then explore, can you post a screenshot of the `contentfulBlog` type and which fields it has?

I can hopefully post a more precise answer if you can share this info, but in the meantime, you might be affected by [Gatsby ignoring empty fields](https://www.gatsbycentral.com/gatsby-ignores-empty-fields).

The article explains in more depth. A short summary, if you have a field which is empty on Contentful, it will not appear in Gatsby. You can make sure you have at least 1 of your records on contentful that has all of your product title fields to solve this.

Comment: Well apparently even i named the fields: product1Title, product2Title,  product3Title etc, all in the same manner,  the auto generated Contentful Field ID's are: product1Title, product2title, product3title etc. There's a capital "T" only in the first one:). GraphiQL tool message: "message": "Cannot query field \"product2Title\" on type \"ContentfulBlog\". Did you mean \"product1Title\", \"product2title\", \"product4title\", \"product5title\", or \"product3title\"?" Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Not sure what's going on there with the field naming though!